# Static constraint on Item

Tags: f#, inline, type-constraints

I'm trying to write a option-valued version of "TryGetValue" that will work on any object that implements either IDictionary or IReadOnlyDictionary. I have this :

```
let inline contains   (key:^key) (dictionary:^dic )=
    (^dic: (member ContainsKey: ^key -> bool) (dictionary, key) ) 

let inline tryGetValue (dictionary:^dic )  (key:^key)=
    if contains key dictionary then  
        let value = ( ^dic : (member  get_Item: ^key -> ^value )  (dictionary, key) )   (dictionary) ) key
        value |> Some
    else None
```

The definition of "value" produces a warning that member constraints with name get_Item have special status which may cause runtime errors. What should I be doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `TryGetValue` instead of `ContainsKey` and `Item`?

```
let inline tryGetValue dic key =
    let mutable value = Unchecked.defaultof< ^value>
    let contains = (^dic : (member TryGetValue : ^key * byref< ^value> -> bool) (dic, key, &value))
    if contains then Some value else None
```

Comment: I started like that, and it was precisely that "Unchecked.defaultof<^value>" or more precisely my not knowing that this existed, that made me stop. Will there not be a lot of types that cause that to throw an exception because they don't have a default?

Comment: @MatthewJohnHeath All types have a default value, it is null for reference types while the default value of a struct is the value produced by setting all value type fields to their default value and all reference type fields to null.